# Pandas rolling function with only dates in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey I have a doubt on pandas rolling function.
I am currently using it to get mean for last 10 days of my time series data.

Example df:

```
             column

2020-12-04    14
2020-12-05    15
2020-12-06    16
2020-12-07    17
2020-12-08    18
2020-12-09    19
2020-12-13    20
2020-12-14    11
2020-12-16    12
2020-12-17    13
```

Usage:

`df['column'].rolling('10D').mean()`

But the function calculates the rolling mean over the 10 calendar days. like if the current row date is  2020-12-17 it calculates till 2020-12-07.

However I would like the rolling mean on the last 10 days that are in the data frame. i.e I would want till 2020-12-04.

How can I acheive it?

Edit: So I can also have a 15 mins interval datetime index so doing window=10 is not helping in that case. Though it works here.

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: Change `"10D"` to `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Just one little detail to remember. You have missing dates in you dataframe. You should fill that, otherwise it will not be a 10 day window. Instead you would have a 10-dates rolling window,which would be pretty meaningless if dates are randoly missing.

```
r = pd.date_range(start=df1.Date.min(), end=df1.Date.max())
df1 = df1.set_index('Date').reindex(r).fillna(0).rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
```

which gives you the dataframe:

```
         Date  column
0  2020-12-04    14.0
1  2020-12-05    15.0
2  2020-12-06    16.0
3  2020-12-07    17.0
4  2020-12-08    18.0
5  2020-12-09    19.0
6  2020-12-10     0.0
7  2020-12-11     0.0
8  2020-12-12     0.0
9  2020-12-13    20.0
10 2020-12-14    11.0
11 2020-12-15     0.0
12 2020-12-16    12.0
13 2020-12-17    13.0
```

Then applying:

```
df1['Mean']=df1['column'].rolling(window=10).mean()
```

returns

```
       Date  column    Mean
0  2020-12-04    14.0   NaN
1  2020-12-05    15.0   NaN
2  2020-12-06    16.0   NaN
3  2020-12-07    17.0   NaN
4  2020-12-08    18.0   NaN
5  2020-12-09    19.0   NaN
6  2020-12-10     0.0   NaN
7  2020-12-11     0.0   NaN
8  2020-12-12     0.0   NaN
9  2020-12-13    20.0  11.9
10 2020-12-14    11.0  11.6
11 2020-12-15     0.0  10.1
12 2020-12-16    12.0   9.7
13 2020-12-17    13.0   9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments by @cs95, if you want to consider only the rows that are in the dataframe, you can ignore that your data is part of a timeseries and just specify a window sized by a number of rows, instead of by a number of days. *In essence*

```
df['column'].rolling(window=10).mean()
```

Comment: So I can also have a 15 mins interval datetime index so doing window=10 is not helping in that case. Though it works here. Have edited the question. Thanks

Comment: @sin.hyp.a Upsample to daily intervals and then use a simple rolling window like here

Comment: @cs95 would not that be really expensive time wise as I will have to merge it again. Is there any other solution? Thanks

Comment: in our defense this is not a typical rolling window request

Comment: @sin.hyp.a Does your dataframe have regularly spaced time intervals? Or is it "randomly" spaced with 15min time deltas ?

Comment: @Ralubrusto It is regular for the most part. 15 minute data from 4:15 am to 10:15 am. 6 Hours window.

Comment: And how do you you expect a "10-days" window to behave in this case? I mean, if the first row is `01/01/2020 4:15:00` you want the mean value until  `01/11/2020 4:15:00` or until  `01/11/2020 10:15:00` ?

Comment: @Ralubrusto Since it is a rolling one yes I would expect the mean value at index 01/11/2020 10:15:00 include till 01/01/2020 10:15:00 if all the dates are there. In case say none of the entries of 01/02/2020 are present I would like it to consider till 12/31/2019 10:15:00

Comment: Hmmm it makes sense. But if just one entry is missing, let's say `01/10/2020 4:00:00`. Should the rolling window go from `01/11/2020 10:15:00` to  `01/01/2020 10:00:00` ? And if  `01/01/2020 10:00:00` is missing as well, it should look for the closest timeindex that exists. Is that right?

Comment: @Ralubrusto I would not mind it. If it makes it easier, I would not mind overseeing the 4:00 condition. Even if one entry of that date is present, I can consider it