# Rolling average by date in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample df below:

```
| date       | group  | price |
|------------|--------|-------|
| 11/25/2020 | cars   | 3     |
| 11/25/2020 | trucks | 2     |
| 11/26/2020 | cars   | 5     |
| 11/26/2020 | trucks | 2     |
| 11/27/2020 | cars   | 3     |
| 11/27/2020 | trucks | 4     |
```

My end goal is to get a rolling cumulative mean of price by date for each group. My desired output is below:

```
| date       | group  | avg_price |
|------------|--------|-----------|
| 11/25/2020 | cars   | 3         |
| 11/26/2020 | cars   | 4         |
| 11/27/2020 | cars   | 3.67      |
| 11/25/2020 | trucks | 2         |
| 11/26/2020 | trucks | 2         |
| 11/27/2020 | trucks | 2.67      |
```

My inital idea is to loop through the df with `df.itertuples()` while having a `while loop` with the date range but I cannot quite figure it out. If anyone has any tips / suggestions for the fastest way to do this that would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this approach, converting the date column to index of the dataframe and then using rolling function for required frequency ? Edit : check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343387/pandas-rolling-function-with-only-dates-in-the-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`expanding().mean()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) for the cumulative mean:

```py
df = df.set_index('date').groupby('group').expanding().mean()

# group  date           price
# cars   11/25/2020  3.000000
#        11/26/2020  4.000000
#        11/27/2020  3.666667
# trucks 11/25/2020  2.000000
#        11/26/2020  2.000000
#        11/27/2020  2.666667
```

To match your exact output, reset the index and rename `price`:

```py
df = df.reset_index().reset_index().rename(columns={'price': 'avg_price'}))

#     group        date  avg_price
# 0    cars  11/25/2020   3.000000
# 1    cars  11/26/2020   4.000000
# 2    cars  11/27/2020   3.666667
# 3  trucks  11/25/2020   2.000000
# 4  trucks  11/26/2020   2.000000
# 5  trucks  11/27/2020   2.666667
```

Comment: What does expanding do? @tdy

Comment: @Vishnudev check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142149/calculate-an-incremental-mean-using-python-pandas

Comment: Oh! Thanks @Anurag . It's like rolling with start index fixed.

Comment: @Vishnudev Yep, but also with `expanding()`, the window size is not constant. It doesn't slide a fixed window like `rolling()` but instead expands the window incrementally.

Comment: Actually I just realized that's what you meant by "start index fixed"